# Hibernate SQL statements are not getting logged in separate log file using log4j in spring boot application

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, log4j2

I have a web application in spring boot + Hibernate + Log4j deployed in JBOSS. All the hibernate sql queries are getting logged in server.log if we use "spring.jpa.show-sql = true" in application.properties. As per the  Hibernate Log4j instruction we need to turn this property to false so that sql statements will get logged in separate log file as per Log4j configuration. If we turn it to false then also sql statements are not logged in separate   log file. All other application related logs are getting logged in separate log file except hibernate logs. Please help to get this issue resolved.

```
Below is the entry in application.properties file.
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.datasource.ucm.default-auto-commit=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false  
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false

# SQL statements and parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

Log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration  monitorInterval="30">

<Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %p %m%n
    </Property>
    <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT">c:/log/VendorPortal</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>

    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
    </Console>

    <!-- File Appender -->
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
        fileName="c:/log/vendorportal.log"
        filePattern="c:/log/vendorportal-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log"
        ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT"
        ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n" />
    </Console>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    <Logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false"
        level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"
        additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE"
        additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Logger>

    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Root>

</Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need place **Log4j config file** in our application. Then insert **Logger** tag in it:

```
<Configuration status="WARN" strict="true">
<Properties>
    <Property name="filename">logfile.log</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Appender type="Console" name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <Layout type="PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </Layout>
    </Appender>
    <Appender type="File" name="FileAppender" fileName="${filename}">
        <Layout type="PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </Layout>
    </Appender>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>..........
......
....
```

Ya ALI

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already having log4j2.xml with the above configuration. Still hibernate log alone is not getting displayed in log file getting created

Comment: I am having similar problem. @Felsia How did you fix it?

Comment: Ali Yaret Soltan

Comment: chakeram......YA ALI.....

Answer (score 0):

As per your query posted, your configuration seems to be corrected.

FROM:

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"
    ....
</Logger>

<Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE"
    ....
</Logger>

<Root level="error">
    ....
</Root>
```

TO:

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"
    ....
</Logger>

<Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE"
    ....
</Logger>

<Root level="DEBUG">
    ....
</Root>
```

As the logging levels are of priority => TRACE > DEBUG > INFO > ERROR > WARN > FATAL

Hope this helps to resolve the issue.